# C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Include takes one argument, Name(s) of the config file(s) to be included

Tags: apache

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMpej.png)
 Syntax error on line 539 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Include takes one argument, Name(s) of the config file(s) to be included; fails if the wildcard does not match at least one file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4X5H.png)

Comment: how to resolve this amy help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Apache `conf` is parsed line by line. Try to put

```
Include C:\3DEXPERIENCE\conf\3dexperience.conf
```

on the same line.

`C:\3DEXPERIENCE\conf\3dexperience.conf` should be the `one argument` of Include in line 539.